# How to trick CompletableFuture.complete() to run dependents/stages in other thread?

Tags: java, completable-future

```
CompletableFuture<Object> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
cf.whenComplete((t, throwable) -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString());
});
cf.complete(new Object());
```

This will run whenComplete's `BiConsumer` callback in the thread calling cf.complete()

How can I run this whenComplete/other lambdas not in the current thread (`commonPool()` ?), while *not* calling `cf.complete()` from the other thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do this in `cd.complete()` level.
The only way is to use

```
cd.whenCompleteAsync()
```

and pass an executor as second parameter.

So it will look like this:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
CompletableFuture<Object> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
cf.whenCompleteAsync((t, throwable) -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString());
}, executor);
cf.complete(new Object());
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that you don't have to create your own executor if you don't want. You can simply use whenCompleteAsync() without the second argument. Then it will run the code in ForkJoin pool's thread.